# Rowspan equivalent using Bootstrap cols?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a setup that looks like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a 3rd column to my layout, that expands down across both rows. The format I am trying to achieve looks like this

```
----------------
|col4|col4|col4|
|---------|    |
|col8     |    |
----------------
```

But I am having trouble finding the proper syntax to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">col 4</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">col 4</div>           
        </div>
        <div class="row">col 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">col 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Check out this [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/Mk0i8xCl9J)

Answer (score 3):

You could use nested columns to achieve this sort of responsive effect.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-info"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-warning"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 bg-success"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 bg-success"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .col-sm-6, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-4 {
        height: 2em;
    }
</style>
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eubum5t3/1/) - try stretching the divider horizontally to see how it looks.