# I want to make an html form with 3x3 grid layout with boostrap, but the layout keeps getting messy

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want to make an html form with 3x3 grid layout with boostrap, but the layout keeps getting messy because at row 2 col 3 the form type is text area and its make a gap in the row below it:

[image]

how can i make the layout is neat like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VSrT.png]

i have tried explore bootstrap attribute however it still cant make the layout correct

Comment: Here are two [ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082032/rowspan-equivalent-using-bootstrap-cols)

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to your ideas @WoAiNii. Thank you very much